# Question about series expansion in "30 years that shook physics"

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am currently reading "30 years that shook physics" (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17265.Thirty_Years_that_Shook_Physics) and on page 159 found the following series:

[image: Page 159, 30 years that shook physics]

Tell me I am not crazy and the text is wrong and the series should evaluate to e and sin(1)? 2.3026 is log(x)/ln(x), and how you would get 0 in the second I don't know.

Comment: You don't sound crazy to me.

Comment: It is obviously a typo. In the italian version of this beautiful book ( written by a great physicist) we read  (pag 155) that the series ..."converge al valore 0,841." That is the correct value.

Comment: @EmilioNovati I just do not believe that this is only a typo ! How should someone get such a value that has absolutely nothing to do with the given sum ?

Comment: @Peter $2.3026 = \log{10},\,$ which appears elsewhere in the book. So itmight be a misguided string replace, or buggy macro, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are perfectly right! I guess something went wrong in the editing of this beautiful book written by [George Gamow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Gamow). This is the same page from the italian version with the correct values:[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is really interesting. I get that 0,8415 lost a few digits (today we would call that a copy&paste error), but I would love to know how e got turned into 2.3026...

Comment: @Julian I don't know... BTW I found the number 2.3026... as an approximation of $\ln(10)$ at p.29 in another Gamow's book https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Two_Three..._Infinity But this time it is in the correct place!